# iOS App Transfer "Unexpected save error"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I'm expecting this annoying error everytime that I had tried to Transfer an App from one account to other.

[image: Unexpected save error]

Previously we had checked following:

- The transferor and the recipient have active developer accounts and
  accepted the most current version of all master agreements that are
  currently in effect
- The app has at least one approved version
- The app
  is in the Ready for Sale, Invalid Binary, Rejected, Developer
  Rejected, or Developer Removed from Sale state
- Any associated In-App
  Purchases are in the Ready to Submit, Ready for Sale, Rejected,
  Developer Removed from Sale, or Approved state
- We know the Apple ID
  of the recipient’s Team Agent and their Team ID

Also, all check marks are on "green" as shown as follows

[image]

Someone has solved this issue? what should I do to accomplish this task?

Comment: Probably a temporary server issue. Try again later.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I had trying several times on different days without success.

Comment: Report the issue to Apple. There's a link in iTunes Connect (Contact Us).